# windows workflow foundation state machine transaction

Tags: transactions, workflow-foundation

is it transaction in windows workflow foundation  state machine .Not in sequential workflow. And how to manage transaction from host?

I have 3 state machine ,Which is calling separately.  if exception thrown by third state machine I want revert 3 state machine in previous state.

Answer (score 1):

If your workflow host has an InstanceStore setup and the state machine has persisted at some point prior to the transaction, when the transaction aborts, the current instance will be abandoned.

The next time you resume the workflow it will resume from the persistence point prior to the transaction.